# Beautiful Hot Soup Web Scaping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
url = 'https://hotcopper.com.au/postview/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
#Get Raw HTML content
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')

stocks =[]
rows = soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'stock-pill-td alt-tr'})
for row in rows:
  name = row.find('a').text.strip()
  stocks.append(name)
print(stocks)
```

Returns  Attribute error

```
---> 12   name = row.find('a').text.strip()
     13   stocks.append(name)
     14 print(stocks)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am attempting to get the ticker text html.Running soup:

```
soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'stock-pill-td alt-tr'})
```

will return a list an I am trying to extract 'NVA' for example

```
<td class="stock-pill-td alt-tr"><span class="stock-pill alt-tr"><a class="tag-type-symbol" href="/asx/nva/" title="NOVA MINERALS LIMITED - Click here for NVA (ASX) posts.">NVA</a></span></td>`enter code here`
```

When I attempt to iterate over the list it throws a attribute error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with some of the empty rows in the table.
Adding try-except block explains it.

```py
import bs4 as bs
import requests
url = 'https://hotcopper.com.au/postview/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
#Get Raw HTML content
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')

stocks =[]
rows = soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'stock-pill-td alt-tr'})
for row in rows:
    try:
        name = row.find('a').get_text()
        stocks.append(name)
    except:
        print(row)
print(stocks)
```

Comment: Thanks Atharva yeah that was the issue. I noticed when I started checking the website table it had empty values.